# ioredis | slotsRefreshTimeout & slotsRefreshInterval meaning

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

Want to understand the meaning of these two fields `slotsRefreshTimeout` & `slotsRefreshInterval` in ioredis library for nodejs. how does it impact the client side if these are set as default values.

I have been seeing some connection issues in the redis in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `slotsRefreshTimeout` and `slotsRefreshInterval` are used by ioredis to adjust the monitoring process of the nodes in a Redis cluster, so that the client can have an up-to-date snapshot of the Redis topology and the distribution of its hash slots: [ioredis keeps a secondary connection](https://github.com/luin/ioredis/blob/3bf300a1c99ae4cf8038930c45e19ebd68db222e/lib/cluster/index.ts#L828) opened against the target node to poll and monitor its clustering and replication information.

From the [ioredis docs](https://github.com/luin/ioredis/blob/main/README.md):

> `slotsRefreshTimeout`: Milliseconds before a timeout occurs while
> refreshing slots from the cluster (default 1000).
>
> `slotsRefreshInterval`: Milliseconds between every automatic slots
> refresh (default 5000).

The default values are fine for most scenarios I can think of.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking, since in the cluster mode there is no reverse proxy which is keeping this hash slot related information i.e. which node in the cluster should be storing this key. that means it's the client's responsibility to keep the up-to-date topology of the redis cluster

Comment: Accepting the answer. Thanks @efran

Comment: As of 1 Nov 2023 by  default  slotsRefreshInterval is disabled. See the doc you have shared.